# Reassign a keyboard shortcut in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to reassign a keyboard shortcut in Chrome.

I found a [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJkx1.png) on API references for a chrome extensions. I want to focus the addressbar, in other words focus on the URL. Something like "Alt+D" does in most browsers. Does anyone know if there's documentation about something like "Chrome.currentTab.focusAddressbar"?
I can't seem to find it...

e.g this works for reloading the current tab:
[image: e.g]

Comment: You must be on the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking questions.

Comment: There's no way to do it using an extension. Use an external program like Autohotkey or similar.